# Is this build.sbt ok for packaging?

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I am trying to package an unmanaged jar along with some Scala code. I program using IntelliJ, and I am not sure if the package is being built correctly.

My `build.sbt` is as follows:

```
name := "InvokeCompiler"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

exportJars := true

val parserLocation = "lib/parser-0.0.1.jar"

mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= {

    _.filter(!_._1.getName.startsWith("Main"))
}

//unmanagedJars in Compile += file(parserLocation)

mappings in (Compile, packageBin) <+= baseDirectory map { base =>

    (base / parserLocation) -> "parser-0.0.1.jar"
}
```

I want to make a new jar file that contains the unmanaged jar and the code I wrote. This jar will be converted to a `.dll` for use it in C#. But, when doing this, IKVMC throws all sorts of warnings. When I add the `.dll` it produces the `.dll` only contains the class I wrote myself.

**EDIT**:
After reading Mr. Ford's comment, here are the warnings and errors I get from running ikvmc on the generated jar:

```
PROMPT:> ikvmc -target:library compiled.jar
IKVM.NET Compiler version 7.2.4630.5
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Jeroen Frijters
http://www.ikvm.net/

note IKVMC0002: Output file is "compiled.dll"
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.nlogo.core.FrontEndInterface" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "scala.Tuple2" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "scala.reflect.ScalaSignature" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "scala.Option" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.nlogo.core.Program" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "scala.collection.immutable.ListMap" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.nlogo.core.ExtensionManager" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.nlogo.core.CompilationEnvironment" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.nlogo.core.Femto$" not found
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "Interface.ASTSingleton$.getFrontEndCompiledAsJSON(Ljava.lang.String;)Lscala.Tuple2;"
    ("org.nlogo.core.FrontEndInterface")
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "Interface.ASTSingleton$.getFrontEndSingletion()Lorg.nlogo.core.FrontEndInterface;"
    ("org.nlogo.core.Femto$")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you're building it, so that might be the first problem. Specifically, you should use the `sbt publish-local` command. To verify that the dependency is include simply unzip the JAR file and look.

If you need the resulting JAR file to be executable, then you should add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
mainClass in Compile := Some("name.of.your.main.Class")
```

Replace `name.of.your.main.Class` with your class name. You are doing something similar but potentially problematic:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= {
    _.filter(!_._1.getName.startsWith("Main"))
}
```

What this means is that anything that has a class name that doesn't start with `Main` will be filtered out. Unless you have a good reason for this, I'd get rid of it and point the package main method explicitly. What `mappings` does is [described here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Package.html#Modify+the+contents+of+the+package).

Comment: I don't want the jar to have a main method, I want it to be a lib, that is all. by extracting the contents of the resulting jar, it seems all of the dependencies are added. Then the question remains why ikvmc can't convert it to dll. Thank you, at least it seems my sbt is ok. :)

Comment: @Marin Happy to help! Remember to upvote and/or accept answers that help you get to a solution, or elucidate that situation. By doing so people will be more likely to help you in the future! I'd also update your original post with the warnings you're getting, as it may provide more clues that will let us help you.